# Eclipse Mars. Java Spring - Maven Profile Switch for Build Environments

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, profile

***@Jarrod Roberson***, Spring in this question is about version 1.2 so the other solution was not possible. This solution uses a simple Maven configuration and Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in applicationContext.xml.

I have upgraded a webapp I work on from Windows XP, Eclipse 3.2 to OS X, Eclipse Mars.

I started with a Dynamic Web Project on Mars and completed the upgrade. I have since converted it to a Maven Project. I was hoping to use Maven Profiles for switching between **Dev** and **Test** environments.

The environments differ only in **config.properties** which gets pulled into **applicationContext.xml**. For **Test** I only intend to export to a war with the 'correct' **config.properties**.

But I **cannot** get the **config.properties** file to be updated from the profile dependent versions when switching profiles.

I have in pom.xml:-

```
<profiles>
    <profile><!-- The configuration of the development profile -->
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile><!-- The configuration of the test profile -->
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <filters>
        <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I feel that I am close but something is missing. I tried adding the maven-resources-plugin but that made no difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind updating your post with your project's structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having your *config.properties* file placed in the *src/* folder you should have it inside your *src/main/resources* folder.

Your project structure should look like this:

```
project-root
    |_ src
      |_ main
        |_ java
        |_ resources
          |_ profiles
            |_ dev
              |_ config.properties
            |_ test
              |_ config.properties
        |_ webapp
          |_ WEB-INF
```

After that you've to change your *pom.xml* in order to include your *config.properties* as a resource.

And notice that the *filters* have been removed since Maven is already filtering your resources when you have `<filtering>true</filtering>`.

Your *pom.xml* will look like this:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Finally, you'll have your *config.properties* inside your WEB-INF/classes folder, according to the selected profile.

Comment: Thanks but it's not doing what I expected/wanted. <profiles> left same as at top. Removed <filters> from <build>. Added <includes> as above. Still not working. I was expecting to see /src/config.properties change from dev to test version etc. or at least WEB-INF/classes/config.properties to change in the war. But nothing. If I switch the the config.properties manually everything works as expected. So, it's just the automatic switch over that is not working.

Comment: Where is the base path of your *config.properties* file? *src/main/resources*?

Comment: @Lyndon, Check my updated answer. I believe it does what you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks aribeiro it's working now. Because I started with a Dynamic Web Application the folder structure is not 'pure' Maven. That is, I have src not src/main/java. But I did create a src/main/resources. I'm going to try some variations and report back...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>profiles/${build.profile.id}</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using a Dynamic Web folder structure not a 'pure' Maven folder structure (eg. src/main/java).

My **profiles** folder is directly under the project (webapp) folder at the same level as **src**. Under profiles I have two folders, **dev** and **test** each with their respective **config.properties** file.

It now works as expected, when I change profile the correct config.properties appears in WEB-INF/classes ready to be picked up by applicationContext.xml...